# Stop function after if condition is met

Tags: jquery, if-statement

running the function below leaves the user with a value of `'8'` in the `<body>`. I'd like to display the ***first*** value that is `> 6` in the body, neglecting the subsequent values. In other words, I'd like the below function display `'7'`.

Is some sort of `while` loop needed here? Any help?

```
var numbers = [0,7,2,5,4,8,2,6];

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
   if (numbers[i] > 6) {
        $('body').html(numbers[i]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

6 will be inserted into your `<body>` but will immediately change since you are allowing your loop to continue.

[Break](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) out of your `for` loop if/when your condition is met:

```
var numbers = [0,7,2,5,4,8,2,6];

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
   if (numbers[i] > 6) {
        $('body').html(numbers[i]);
        break;
   }
}
```

If, as your title implies, this code is within a function, you can also `return`. This will prevent any further code in that function from being executed (including the rest of the loop.)